# XPATH to return all nodes within a node where 1st original node is selectable

Tags: xml, xpath

This XPATH is very new to me. How would I return all the nodes within one of the PERSON nodes based up the dob node being equal to something, like in this case 19531119. So If I have whats below on my initial returned query, how would I get it to display whats below it using xpath. This has to be so simple for someone to try to help me.

```
<ELIGIBILITY>
  <PERSON>
    <name>Abe Lincoln</name>
    <last_name>Lincoln</last_name>
    <first_name>Nancy</first_name>
    <dob>19550918</dob>
    <from_date>20171001</from_date>
    <thru_date>20200831</thru_date>
    <medical>active</medical>    
  </PERSON>
<PERSON>
    <name>Martha Washington</name>
    <last_name>Washington</last_name>
    <first_name>Martha</first_name>
    <dob>19531119</dob>
    <from_date>20171001</from_date>
    <thru_date>20200831</thru_date>
    <medical>inactive</medical>
</PERSON>
</ELIGIBILITY>
```

I need this returned based upon the dob matching 19531119

```
<PERSON>
    <name>Martha Washington</name>
    <last_name>Washington</last_name>
    <first_name>Martha</first_name>
    <dob>19531119</dob>
    <from_date>20171001</from_date>
    <thru_date>20200831</thru_date>
    <medical>inactive</medical>
</PERSON>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is more efficient XPath expression.

Double forward slash `//` will be traversing the entire XML document. No need to do that.

```
/ELIGIBILITY/PERSON[dob="19531119"]
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried the 1st suggestion and I found that I had to take out the // before the dob in the brackets for it to work, and it did work then, so I have been playing around with that one, and I then discovered what you wrote and that worked too and I get it about not  traversing the entire DOC, Im learning. You answer works perfect in an online xpath tester but Im using this in a Cisco UCCX IVR script, and it just does not work, the result comes up null on the same data with the same xpath that worked in the online tester. I am truly stumped but it is now a Cisco problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression:

```
//PERSON[//dob='19531119']
```

and see if it works.